Discovery studio has messed up the 2D structure of ligand and protein interactions
When I put it to see the interactions resulting from a docking between the human albumin protein and porphyrin, the 2D diagram of the porphyrin macro cycle gets all messed up and overlaps the bonds, while the 3D is ok and the docking too. It seems that when the ligands are more complex, this program breaks down. I tested both the 2019 and 2024 versions and it gives the same result shown below.

Does anyone know how I can fix this without having to drag each link to its proper place manually?

https://www.3ds.com/support/
